# "it" as a true/logical subject or preparatory subject

Tags: word-usage, dummy-it, it-its-itself

I have a difficult time to analyse "it" as the true/logical subject or preparatory subject in a article, like this sentence:

> In rejecting probability, and the larger area of mathematical statistics within which **it** belonged, China's statisticians discarded a large array of techniques, none more critical than the era's newest and most exciting fact generating technology—large-scale random sampling.

From Aeon article " Counting China"

Would you please help me understanding the it refer to...

Comment: "It" probably refers to "probability".  And note that the dash after "technology" should be an em-dash, not a hyphen.

Comment: It has "probability" as antecedent, (_the larger area of mathematical statistics within which probability belonged_).

Comment: Thank you, Hot Licks. I edited the em-dash after “ technology ”. And thank your for the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Bill J.

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to "probability" because probability theory is a part of statistical science according to a certain point of view ([ref.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8536)).

Comment: Thank you, LPH.